# Singelton implementation to read / write from server

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to implement a singelton to read / write from a simple chat server. Im using a singelton model so that i can access the data and write from all of my viewControllers.

My singelton code:

```
#import "ChatDataController.h"

@implementation ChatDataController
{
    ChatDataController * anotherSingles;
}

@synthesize enString;
@synthesize enInt;


+(ChatDataController *) singlOjb {

    static ChatDataController * single=nil;

    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if(!single)
        {
            single = [[ChatDataController alloc] init];
        }
    }

    return single;
}


// We can still have a regular init method, that will get called the first time the Singleton is used.
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        // Work your initialising magic here as you normally would

        [self initNetworkCommunication];
    }

    return self;
}

// Open connection to server
- (void)initNetworkCommunication {
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"localhost", 8080, &readStream, &writeStream);
    inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
    outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];

    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];
}

- (void) sendMsg {
    NSString *response  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"iam:TestString"];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[response dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
}

@end
```

The problem is that when i run `[self initNetworkCommunication];` from my `init` method my app crashes with the error: `(lldb)`

A break is detected at the line:
`inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;`

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

EDIT: Is this the way i should be doing it?

Comment: you just casted your readstream and writestream to cfreadstram cfwritestream but did you created thoses object somewhere before in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your singleton code should be like this...

```
+ (ChatDataController *)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static ChatDataController *chatDataController;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^ { chatDataController = [[ChatDataController alloc] init];});
    return chatDataController;
}
```

Next, and I'm not sure is this will fix as I'm not sure of the exact problem but I would do it this way...

In your AppDelegate (or wherever you need to start the stream) do this...

```
[[ChatDataController sharedInstance] initNetworkCommunication];
```

This makes sure the singleton object is fully instantiated before calling its instance methods.